# IMFSourceReader.ReadSample never hitting callback after reading on stream 1. calls to stream 0 work fine

Tags: webcam, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

So background im working on reworking an application that was using direct show to use Windows Media Foundation. in Directshow i have UVC camera still pins working fine. however when i switched to using a SourceReader in WMF i have stream 0 (the live video stream) however when i use the same interface to try and request samples on Stream1 i dont receive anything. This is with the following call.

```
hr = StreamReader.ReadSample(1,
                            MediaFoundation.ReadWrite.MF_SOURCE_READER_CONTROL_FLAG.None,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            IntPtr.Zero
                            );
```

if i switch it to

```
hr = StreamReader.ReadSample(1,
                        MediaFoundation.ReadWrite.MF_SOURCE_READER_CONTROL_FLAG.Drain,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        IntPtr.Zero
                        );
```

i receive only null IMFSamples. ive checked the state of hr and it is always S_OK. During this time i am also running the same call but on stream 0 and it is working fine. The only error or flag i get is StreamTick on the first frame on stream 0.

Im not entirely sure where to go from here if anyone has suggestions im open

Edit1:
I do have streams selected for both and the desired MediaTypes set with SetCurrentMediaType

Comment: Maybe you also have stream 2 and it corresponds to pin 1 in DirectShow (and does work as you expect).

Comment: @reply  Roman R. There are only 2 streams available on the device when i check so it should still be stream 1.

Comment: I don't think you are expected to do anything besides the media type making sure the stream is selected. I would say that the most likely reason is the driver malfunction. Operation of the DirectShow pin is important observation but it does not prove the device is fully valid and compatible with MF as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`IMFSourceReader::SetStreamSelection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader-setstreamselection) method to configure the reader and set it to expect or not expect samples on specific streams. You need to make sure you selected the stream before reading from it.

Comment: I Have both stream 1 and 0 selected. when it was unselected i was getting an error in the onreadsample callback still though ( i beleive it was invalid request)